# Can FormFlow Dialogs be built with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, botframework, formflow

The Bot Framework FAQ (http://docs.botframework.com/faq/#what-does-the-bot-builder-sdk-provide-to-developers-how-does-it-work) states that Bot Builder SDK allows developers to build "FormFlow” dialogs to help with tricky issues such as multi-turn and disambiguation, but I can only find FormFlow discussed in the C# documentation.

Can FormFlow dialogs be built with the Node.js SDK?  If so, can someone please point me to the documentation?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, FormFlow uses .NET reflection to infer information from your data structures to build a dialog.