# Multiple choice prompt with Node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I would like to create a choice prompt in Node.js that allows the user to make multiple selections, just like in FormFlow for .NET (see the toppings prompt of the [Simple Sandwich Bot](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html#simpleSandwichBot)).

Is there maybe already some sample code available that I could adapt? Would this also be possible with buttons instead of a list?

Comment: I'm also looking for the multiple choice prompt for the Microsoft Bot Framework. if you found anything please answer your question. thanks

Comment: One possible way to do this is to use the Customize Prompt with a Simple Dialog.

Comment: Maybe we could give some more attention to the implementation of this feature. Please express your interest @ https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2091

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can FormFlow Dialogs be built with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925856/can-formflow-dialogs-be-built-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently available in the Node.js SDK for BotBuilder.  It is only available in the .NET version.  [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925856/can-formflow-dialogs-be-built-with-node-js?rq=1)

Answer (score -2):

maybe you are looking for sth like this? npm install prompt --save

although, it doesnt have a button, for that u would need and interface, ui, but not a prompt in a command console

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

prompt.get(['choice'], function(err, result) {
    if (result.choice == "0") {
          //selects multiple choice 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Leandro, thanks, but I am looking for a multiple choice prompt for the Microsoft Bot Framework, and not node.js in general.